# Selenium using Java code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error While running Selenium in Netbeans through IE 11

> org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0

Comment: what's your selenium version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a wrong Java version or a old Selenium or a combination. Update everything to the latest versions.